# EditText in Android did not display its value until it has focus

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I'm having a hard time resolving this problem which is probably basic to others. I cannot find where I made a mistake. I am trying to retrieve all the information about the selected institution name and set it on the editText when it has the corresponding value needed. I was able to retrieve all the data(I log it down to logcat to check if it really has value), but it is not displaying on the editText until the time I click it. I've tried to invalidate and even request for focus on the editText but no work. I really cannot figure it out. I attached a picture of my screen and post the xml for that layout. Thanks in advance to those who will help me.[image]

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_complete_address"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/rel_ca">

            <TableLayout
                android:id="@+id/tbl_2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tbl2_row1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/lbl_bldg_name"
                        android:layout_width="210dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
                        android:text="@string/lbl_bldgname"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="18sp" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/txt_bldg_name"
                        android:layout_width="485dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/img_edittext_bg"
                        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                        android:inputType="textCapWords"
                        android:nextFocusDown="@+id/txt_bldg_no"
                        android:padding="3dp"
                        android:textSize="18sp" 
                        android:singleLine="true"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/lbl_bldg_no"
                        android:layout_width="140dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
                        android:text="@string/lbl_bldgno"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="18sp" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/txt_bldg_no"
                        android:layout_width="340dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/img_edittext_bg"
                        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                        android:inputType="textCapWords"
                        android:nextFocusDown="@+id/txt_street_name"
                        android:padding="3dp"
                        android:textSize="18sp" 
                        android:singleLine="true"/>
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tbl2_row2"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp" >

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/linear_name1"
                        android:layout_width="215dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
                        android:orientation="horizontal" >

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="*"
                            android:textColor="@color/red"
                            android:textSize="18sp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/lbl_street_name"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="@string/lbl_street_name"
                            android:textColor="@color/black"
                            android:textSize="18sp" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/txt_street_name"
                        android:layout_width="485dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/img_edittext_bg"
                        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                        android:inputType="textCapWords"
                        android:nextFocusDown="@+id/txt_street_no"
                        android:padding="3dp"
                        android:textSize="18sp" 
                        android:singleLine="true"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/lbl_street_no"
                        android:layout_width="140dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
                        android:text="@string/lbl_street_no"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="18sp" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/txt_street_no"
                        android:layout_width="340dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/img_edittext_bg"
                        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                        android:inputType="textCapWords"
                        android:nextFocusDown="@+id/txt_brgy"
                        android:padding="3dp"
                        android:textSize="20sp" 
                        android:singleLine="true"/>
                </TableRow>
            </TableLayout>

            <TableLayout
                android:id="@+id/tbl_3"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/tbl_2"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp" >

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tbl3_row1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/linear_name1"
                        android:layout_width="215dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
                        android:orientation="horizontal" >

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="*"
                            android:textColor="@color/red"
                            android:textSize="18sp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/lbl_brgy"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="@string/lbl_brgy"
                            android:textColor="@color/black"
                            android:textSize="18sp" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/txt_brgy"
                        android:layout_width="975dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/img_edittext_bg"
                        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                        android:inputType="textCapWords"
                        android:padding="3dp"
                        android:textSize="18sp" 
                        android:singleLine="true"/>
                </TableRow>
            </TableLayout>

            <TableLayout
                android:id="@+id/tbl_4"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/tbl_3"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp" >

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tbl4_row1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/linear_name3"
                        android:layout_width="215dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
                        android:orientation="horizontal" >

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="*"
                            android:textColor="@color/red"
                            android:textSize="18sp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/lbl_city"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="@string/lbl_city"
                            android:textColor="@color/black"
                            android:textSize="18sp" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <Spinner
                        android:id="@+id/spn_city"
                        android:layout_width="485dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/img_spinner_background"
                        android:padding="3dp" />
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tbl4_row2"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp" >

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/linear_name3"
                        android:layout_width="215dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
                        android:orientation="horizontal" >

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="*"
                            android:textColor="@color/red"
                            android:textSize="18sp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/lbl_province"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="@string/lbl_province"
                            android:textColor="@color/black"
                            android:textSize="18sp" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <Spinner
                        android:id="@+id/spn_province"
                        android:layout_width="485dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/img_spinner_background"
                        android:padding="3dp"
                        android:textSize="20sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/lbl_zipcode"
                        android:layout_width="140dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
                        android:text="@string/lbl_zipcode"
                        android:textSize="18sp" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/txt_zipcode"
                        android:layout_width="190dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/img_edittext_bg"
                        android:digits="1234567890"
                        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                        android:inputType="number"
                        android:nextFocusDown="@+id/txt_lname"
                        android:padding="3dp"
                        android:textSize="20sp" 
                        android:singleLine="true"/>
                </TableRow>
            </TableLayout>

            <TableLayout
                android:id="@+id/tbl_5"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/tbl_4" >

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tbl4_row3"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp" >

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="215dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
                        android:orientation="horizontal" >

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="*"
                            android:textColor="@color/red"
                            android:textSize="18sp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/lbl_telno"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="@string/lbl_telno"
                            android:textColor="@color/black"
                            android:textSize="18sp" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/txt_country_code"
                        android:layout_width="85dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/img_edittext_bg"
                        android:digits="1234567890"
                        android:hint="Country Code"
                        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                        android:inputType="number"
                        android:maxLength="2"
                        android:nextFocusDown="@+id/txt_area_code"
                        android:padding="3dp"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:textSize="18sp" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/img_dash" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/txt_area_code"
                        android:layout_width="85dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/img_edittext_bg"
                        android:digits="1234567890"
                        android:hint="Area Code"
                        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                        android:inputType="number"
                        android:maxLength="2"
                        android:nextFocusDown="@+id/txt_phone_no"
                        android:padding="3dp"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:textSize="18sp" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/img_dash" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/txt_phone_no"
                        android:layout_width="130dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/img_edittext_bg"
                        android:digits="1234567890"
                        android:hint="Phone Number"
                        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                        android:inputType="number"
                        android:maxLength="7"
                        android:nextFocusDown="@+id/txt_faxcountry_code"
                        android:padding="3dp"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:textSize="18sp" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btn_add_telno"
                        android:layout_width="65dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/img_gray_unpress"
                        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                        android:paddingRight="10dp"
                        android:text="@string/btn_add"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/lbl_telefax_no"
                        android:layout_width="216dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
                        android:text="@string/lbl_faxno"
                        android:textSize="18sp" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/txt_faxcountry_code"
                        android:layout_width="85dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/img_edittext_bg"
                        android:digits="1234567890"
                        android:hint="Country Code"
                        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                        android:inputType="number"
                        android:maxLength="2"
                        android:nextFocusDown="@+id/txt_faxarea_code"
                        android:padding="3dp"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:textSize="18sp" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/img_dash" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/txt_faxarea_code"
                        android:layout_width="85dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/img_edittext_bg"
                        android:digits="1234567890"
                        android:hint="Area Code"
                        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                        android:inputType="number"
                        android:maxLength="2"
                        android:nextFocusDown="@+id/txt_faxphone_no"
                        android:padding="3dp"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:textSize="18sp" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/img_dash" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/txt_faxphone_no"
                        android:layout_width="130dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/img_edittext_bg"
                        android:digits="1234567890"
                        android:hint="Phone Number"
                        android:inputType="number"
                        android:maxLength="7"
                        android:padding="3dp"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:textSize="18sp" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btn_add_faxno"
                        android:layout_width="65dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/img_gray_unpress"
                        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                        android:paddingRight="10dp"
                        android:text="@string/btn_add"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </TableRow>
            </TableLayout>


        </RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the code where i retrieve and set the data to the editText:

```
Cursor c_details = db_Handler.get_Institution_Details(_institutionID);
    if(c_details.getCount() != 0){
        for (c_details.moveToFirst(); !c_details.isAfterLast(); c_details.moveToNext()) {
            l_accountClassificationId = c_details.getString(c_details.getColumnIndex(Constants.INSTITUTION_ACCOUNT_CLASSIFICATION_ID));

            l_bldgName = c_details.getString(c_details.getColumnIndex(Constants.INSTITUTION_BLDG_NAME));
            l_bldgNo = c_details.getString(c_details.getColumnIndex(Constants.INSTITUTION_BLDG_LEVEL_NO));

            g_streetName = c_details.getString(c_details.getColumnIndex(Constants.INSTITUTION_STREET_NAME));
            l_streetNo =  c_details.getString(c_details.getColumnIndex(Constants.INSTITUTION_STREET_NO));
            g_barangay = c_details.getString(c_details.getColumnIndex(Constants.INSTITUTION_BBV));

            l_cityId = c_details.getString(c_details.getColumnIndex(Constants.INSTITUTION_CITY_ID));
            l_provinceId =  c_details.getString(c_details.getColumnIndex(Constants.INSTITUTION_PROVINCE_ID));

            //l_tel_1 = 

            g_zipcode = c_details.getString(c_details.getColumnIndex(Constants.INSTITUTION_ZIPCODE));
            g_cp_employee_population = c_details.getString(c_details.getColumnIndex(Constants.INSTITUTION_EMPLOYEE_POPULATION));
            l_cp_classification =  c_details.getString(c_details.getColumnIndex(Constants.INSTITUTION_EMPLOYEE_CLASSIFICATION));


            Log.i("DETAILS===========", "============================================");
            Log.i("l_accountClassificationId", l_accountClassificationId);
            Log.i("l_bldgName", l_bldgName);
            Log.i("l_bldgNo", l_bldgNo);
            Log.i("l_streetName", g_streetName);
            Log.i("l_streetNo", l_streetNo);
            Log.i("l_barangay", g_barangay);
            Log.i("l_cityId", l_cityId);
            Log.i("l_provinceId", l_provinceId);
            Log.i("l_zipcode", g_zipcode);
            Log.i("l_cp_employee_population", g_cp_employee_population);
            Log.i("l_cp_classification", l_cp_classification);

            Cursor c_provinceName = db_Handler.get_provinceName(l_provinceId);
            Cursor c_cityName = db_Handler.get_cityName(l_cityId);
            Cursor c_accountClassification = db_Handler.get_account_classification_name(l_accountClassificationId);
            if(c_provinceName.getCount() != 0){
                g_province = c_provinceName.getString(c_provinceName.getColumnIndex(Constants.PROVINCE_NAME));
            }else{

            }

            if(c_cityName.getCount() != 0){
                g_city = c_cityName.getString(c_cityName.getColumnIndex(Constants.CITY_NAME));
            }else{

            };

            int _cityPos = 0;
            int _provincePos = 0;
            int _classificationPos = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < l_arrayListCity.size(); i++) {
                if(g_city.equals(l_arrayListCity.get(i))){
                    _cityPos = i;
                }
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < l_arrayListProvince.size(); i++) {
                if(g_province.equals(l_arrayListProvince.get(i))){
                    _provincePos = i;
                }
            }

            g_accountClassification = c_accountClassification.getString(c_accountClassification.getColumnIndex(Constants.ACCOUNT_CLASSIFICATION_NAME));

            for (int i = 0; i < l_arrayListAccountClassification.size(); i++) {
                if(g_accountClassification.equals(l_arrayListAccountClassification.get(i))){
                    _classificationPos = i;
                }
            }

            spn_acct_classification.setSelection(_classificationPos);
            txt_bldg_name.setText(l_bldgName);
            txt_bldg_no.setText(l_bldgNo);
            txt_street_name.setText(g_streetName);
            txt_street_no.setText(l_streetNo);
            txt_brgy.setText(g_barangay);
            txt_zipcode.setText(g_zipcode);
            spn_city.setSelection(_cityPos);
            spn_province.setSelection(_provincePos);
            txt_emp_population.setText(g_cp_employee_population);
            txt_classification.setText(l_cp_classification);
            txt_bldg_name.requestFocus();
        }
    }
```

UPDATE: After some more debugging, i found out that the reason why it is not setting text to editText is because of the spinner itself. I tried to call the method which display above(code that display all the details and set on editext) in a button and remove the spinner.setSelection(0) and it works fine. I don't know what is something in the spinner why i got that problem.

SOLUTION MADE: I solved that problem by changing its xml. Removing the editText inside the table layout. I don't exactly know why, but that works perfectly.

Comment: post the code where you fill in the edit texts programatically, may be ...

Comment: @njzk2 i've posted it. Thanks!

Comment: I assume this `txt_bldg_name.setText(l_bldgName);` sets the text in the `@+id/txt_bldg_name` edittext? 1 thing I don't get in your code is the reason for the `for` loop on all values from the database. Don't you want only one? Also, in what thread is all that happening ? And is there anywhere else where you change the content of this EditText ?

Comment: yes it is. I make a loop just to test something. That happens when I select a value on the spinner for institution name where the editText supposedly will update automatically too but what happens is that it is displaying the value after it was click. Yes, when the index of spinner is in 0, all the editText should be cleared and it is working fine.

Comment: is it possible that this `index of the spinner is in 0` thing is deleting the text at some point ?

Comment: yes it will clear the text but once you change the index of the spinner it will again put values on the strings and set it to the EditText. so i think there is no problem on that

Comment: I tried to remove the setting of selection in the spinner and it works.

Answer (score 0):

If your'e setting your string on your edittext via asynctask, make sure that progress dialog has dismissed first ( normally dismiss on onpost method of asynctask ), there must be a conflict between this two. This solved my problem. hope its helpful on some. :D